# vbscript Type mismatch error when calling function

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

I am running into the Type Mismatch error when I attempt to call a function I created.

Example:

```
Function DoThis(paramA, paramB, paramC)
    If paramA = "Something" Then
        DoThis = DoSomething
    ElseIf paramA = "This" Then 
        DoThis = DoSomethingDifferent
    Else
        DoThis = DoThisOtherThing   
    End If
End Function
Dim result: result = DoThis(valueA, ValueB, ValueC)
```

Can anyone see what my mistake could be? Other functions are working correctly. I have double checked the spelling by actually copying and pasting the function name where I call it. I have verified that the function name is not used anywhere else, i.e., as a constant or something else.

Note that when debugging this the ValType for all arguments is vbString. Also I am never able to enter the function, so it is not like I am debugging the function, enter it and then get the type mismatch.

ty.

Comment: Type Mismatch error: You attempted to compare values of incompatible data types. For example, comparing a string and a numeric value.

_To correct this error_:
+++Make sure the data types match when performing comparisons.
+++Cast one of the values to the data type of the other, and try the comparison again. And `EndIf` should be `End If`

Comment: `EndIf` should be `End If`. Then the code is sytactically correct; the error is caused by code you didn't publish.

Comment: Note that the above is just pseudo code to reduce complexity. Yes, I had a typo when I first typed this. My existing code resembles the pseudo code but it was only to illustrate that the function returns a value and that the function involves decision paths.

Comment: @JosefZ, Thank you. While debugging this I did confirm that all value types supplied to the method are vbString types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VBScript` has only one data type called a *Variant*. A *Variant* is a special kind of data type that can contain different kinds of information, depending on how it is used. Because *Variant* is the only data type in `VBScript`, it is also the data type returned by all functions in `VBScript`.

There are some subtypes of data that a *Variant* can contain (e.g. `Empty, Null, string, integer, object, array` etc.) You can use some *conversion functions* to convert data from one subtype to another, if that conversion is not implicit in `VBScript`. Now, pay your attention to real, factual data subtype of `True` and `vbTrue`.

The **True** keyword (**boolean** literal) has a value (inner representation) equal to -1.

On the other hand, **vbTrue** is one of few built-in constants and, in despite of it's name, has a subtype of **Integer**! It's one of so-called *Tristate* Constants:

```
Constant     Value  Description  
vbUseDefault  -2    Use default from computer's regional settings.
vbTrue        -1    True
vbFalse        0    False
```

I hope next code could make clear all above statements:

```
Wscript.Echo _
 vbTrue, CStr( vbTrue), VarType( vbTrue), TypeName( vbTrue) , _
 vbNewLine, True, CStr( True), VarType( True), TypeName( True)
```

However, used with `If _condition_ Then ...`, there are some particularities; in brief: 
The `Then` part of the `If ...` statement conditionally executes groups of statements only when a single test *If condition* **is not** `False`, i.e. any non-zero number esteems to be true, not only -1. Therefore you are able to use whatever variable or expression (numeric or string) you choose as long as the result is numeric...

Summarizing: `If _expr_ Then ...` is the same as 
`If CBool(_expr_) Then ...`

Comment: JosefZ, Thanks for the comments. I had realized that vbScript used variants and it should have been a non-issue but when I encountered the error that is when I started testing varType on the values as they were populated just in case there was something I was missing. But in this case I was over thinking it and did not just simply try to recreate the function. :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason why retval is retuning mismatch error because it has a numeric value and an alpha value and wsh does not like that.

Answer (score 0):

A sure way to get a type mismatch error for the published code is to define DoSomething etc. as **Subs** (which seems probable, given the names).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why this was a problem, but today I reduced the function down to a simple boolean return value and I still got the type mismatch error.

So I then created a new function with the same parameters and such. When I changed the call to the new function the error goes away.

My original function with the simple boolean return:(MISMATCH ERROR)

```
Function IsInstalledCheck(valueToCheck, expectedValue, checkType)

    IsInstalledCheck = vbFalse

End Function
```

My new function with the a simple return:(Works)

```
Function IsItemInstalled(valueToCheck, expectedValue, checkType)

    IsItemInstalled = vbFalse

End Function
```

EDIT
Note that I had tried this with the standard True / False values as well. The solution was to simply recreated the same function with a new name and for whatever magical reason that worked. The function signature was the same, the order of variables, variable names, the test conditions, everything in the body of the new function is the same.

Comment: Note that I had attempted the return value with vbFalse and FALSE and the results were the same for both tests.